# OWL Protoge Superproperty of (Chain) to produce new Object Property

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, protege

I've a model that allows users to define entities with `myonto:Entity` types, and link them via `myonto:Relationship` nodes, which are attached using `myonto:RelationshipEntityFrom` and `myonto:RelationshipEntityTo` object properties (each with a Domain of Relationship and a Range of Entity)

Given that `myonto:Relationship` has a property :name, what I'd like to do is create an Object Property Class `myonto:EntityToEntityRelationship` that applies according to the following property chain:

```
 inverse (RelationshipEntityFrom) o RelationshipEntityTo
```

So far so good - but what I'd really like to do, is create an Object Property according to the above rules, but as a SubClass of `myonto:EntityToEntityRelationship` using the `:name` of the `myonto:Relationship` individual. This allows the user to define these EntityToEntityRelationship properties by creating individuals of type `myonto:Relationship`.

I can probably do this by means of code as/when these Relationship nodes are created, but I'd rather be able to do it through the reasoner, and have the logic embedded in the ontology.

Is this use of individuals to define and create specific properties (of a particular Super-Type, i.e. SubClasses of Object Properties) something that's possible without recourse to external programming? If so, how would I do this (ideally using Protégé, but if not possible, then directly using owl?

The more sense I can embed into my ontology the better.

To provide more context, here's a version of the sparql query I'm currently running:

```
   SELECT ?s ?p ?o
                    WHERE 
                    {
                        {
                            ?s ^ myonto:RelationshipEntityFrom/myonto:RelationshipEntityTo  ?o .
                            ?r myonto:RelationshipEntityTo ?o.
                            ?r rdfs:label ?rl .
                            ?r a myonto:Relationship .
                            BIND (?rl as ?p)
                        }
                        UNION
                        {
                            ?q ^ myonto:RelationshipEntityFrom/myonto:RelationshipEntityTo ?s .
                            ?s rdfs:label ?o .
                            BIND (rdfs:label as ?p).
                            
                        }
                        UNION
                        {
                            ?s ^ myonto:RelationshipEntityFrom/myonto:RelationshipEntityTo ?q .
                            ?s rdfs:label ?o .
                            BIND (rdfs:label as ?p).
                            
                        }
                        }
```

Which generates a result that "Object-Property-ises" the Relationship entities ConveysProduct, hasPolicy, residesAt into pseudo-object-properties.

[image]

What I'd like to be able to do is some owl-based reasoning that will generate those transformed pseudo-properties, so I can run the following sparql, and get much the same results:

```
    select ?s ?p ?o 
WHERE
{
    {
    ?s ?p ?o.
    ?p rdfs:SubPropertyOf myonto:EntityToEntityRelationship.
    }
    UNION
    {
    ?s ?q ?r.
    ?q rdfs:SubPropertyOf myonto:EntityToEntityRelationship.
    ?s rdfs:label ?o .
    BIND( rdfs:label ?p) .
    }
    UNION
    {
    ?r ?q ?s.
    ?q rdfs:SubPropertyOf myonto:EntityToEntityRelationship.
    ?s rdfs:label ?o .
    BIND( rdfs:label ?p) .
    }
    
}
```

(I'm aware the UNION-ed statements to retrieve the labels are a bit clunky, but it's the simplification of that first where clause I'm looking to investigate.

Comment: It is really difficult to follow what your are asking as you seem to mixing object oriented thinking into ontologies. I.e. there is no such thing as an object property class, you cannot subclass an object property - though you can have a sub property, it is unclear what `:name` is. If you provide a minimal complete ontology and then ask for the specific inference you want in terms of your ontology, it can help to clarify your question.

Comment: If you are interesting in how OO relates to OWL you can have look at [my blog](https://henrietteharmse.com) and in specific [why properties are not relations between classes](https://henrietteharmse.com/2018/06/22/a-common-misconception-regarding-owl-properties/), [the difference between OWL and OO](https://henrietteharmse.com/2018/04/15/object-oriented-features-that-owl-lacks/) and the [translation from UML to OWL](https://henrietteharmse.com/uml-vs-owl/).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Henriette - I'm aiming to use an ontology to provide a logical framework into which data can be loaded. Once loaded, I'd like to be able to create generic convenience methods for querying that data. In this case `:name` is just a data-property that's commonly associated with an item of type `myonto:Relationship`. Users are uploading their datamodels, and I want different ways to reflect those models back to them and to compare them against one another. One such convenience is this switch between relationship-as-entity vs relationship-as-property transformation.